# How to develop a distributed application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, distributed

I am going to develop a distributed application and i haven't develop distributed application
before so i have many questions in my head so to explain these question I'm going to use a scenario

my application will be used in a city called "dreams"

in this city there is a building in north of the city called "A".
this building has server and there is a DBMS installed on it let's say an Oracle 10g as an example

and in the east and the west of our "dreams" city there is 2 buildings one called "B" and the other called "C" in these two building there is many tellers how use my application to store and retrieve information from our database which is installed on the server in the building "A"

*notice: that thees building is not wired connected !

i hope to find a good suggestions and guides from you.

thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is more the job of the system admin than of the programmer. There are two typical solutions:

- Configure your firewall on building A with NAT to your DB server on a certain port. Then connect to the public IP or DNS and port of building A from building B and C.
- Configure a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Developing distributed applications is much the same unless you are using a platform designed for concurrency and distributed processing like Erlang.

The principles for C#, Java and the rest are the same. If your application consists of a multi-tier setup with many application instances connecting to a database then there isn't much you need to worry about. Locking semantics, transactions and state integrity are implemented in the database but you still need to know the fundamentals.

If you are taking a custom approach where you are writing the data storage engine or backend (instead of oracle or another RDBMS) then you **do** need to know the down and dirty of distributed and concurrent systems. You will have to deal with time, state, concurrency control, redundancy and tons of other stuff.

As I say, if it is a traditional database backed application, then you just need to know the basics and where problems will arise in Oracle itself, what you need to lock (if anything)..

If you want to learn the basics, start with thread and async programming stuff and work your way up to network distributed systems.

Hope that helps in some way